# Node Javascript Tiny CC

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the tiny.cc REST API from Node, but seem to be hitting an issue since the Server always responds with a message 'Missing input parameters'.

```html
var message = JSON.stringify({
  "urls": [
    {
      "long_url": "http://example.com",
    }
  ]
});
var https_options = {
    host: 'tinycc.com',
    path: '/tiny/api/3/urls/',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Content-Length': message.length
    }
}

var req = https.request(https_options,res => {
        var msg = '';
        res.on('data',d => msg += d);
        res.on('end',() => {
            console.log('end',JSON.parse(msg));
        });
    });
    req.on('error',e => console.log('tinyURL error',e));
    req.write(message);
    req.end();
```

The response is always

```html
{ 
  error: { 
    code: 1305, 
    message: 'Missing input parameters', 
    details: '' 
  },
  version: '3.1' 
}
```

Comment: You could be right there - buy I'm including everything required by the tiny cc documentation ( it only wants Auth & long_url ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library are you using for making the API call, but I think you will be better using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and including your payload as the body on your post request rather than using the more manual method of writing to the request.

```
var message = {
  "urls": [
    {
      "long_url": "http://example.com",
    }
  ]
};
var options = {
    host: 'tinycc.com',
    path: '/tiny/api/3/urls/',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    body: message,
    json: true,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Content-Length': message.length,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
request(options, console.log)
```

Comment: tiny cc responded - I was missing `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Comment: @user3094755 as @Danielo515 displayed in answer  `json: true` is not working?

Comment: It might well be that `json: true` in the request library has the same effect as adding  `'Content-Type': 'application/json'``, but I didn't need to add the request library.

Comment: Yes, adding JSON true should setup the request properly. The good thing about the request library is that it takes care of a lot of details in the correct way. Not sure if finally you get it working or not